# How can I remove trailing whitespace from a hunk in Magit?

Tags: emacs, whitespace, magit

Emacs (post v21) includes a function to [delete trailing whitespace](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Useless-Whitespace.html) from a file. How would I make `delete-trailing-whitespace` available in the Magit staging area (from `magit-status`) so that I can remove trailing whitespace from individual hunks or entire files?

Comment: Now, I tried `magit`. My guess that you could edit the diffs does not look good. This sort of works with `ediff`-patching but not with git. So, I will delete my answer. I am very sorry about that.

Comment: Magit maintainer here. Magit does not support this.

Comment: @Tobias No worries—as I recall, you were still right in that I could go right to the file from within Magit.  From there its a pretty simple function call.

Comment: @tarsius Not yet ;) I've got a working function; I just can't seem to hook it onto the statues-mode-map.

Comment: Well, from the currently-selected file, at least: https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/8177389

Comment: You might wanna post your snippet as an answer. It's good enough, there are of course a few things that could be improved, i.e. make sure we actually are on a file and don't kill the buffer if it already existed before using this command.

Comment: Why don't you remove trailing whitespace on save, with `(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)`?

Comment: @torazaburo In this case, as I recall, it would've created an obscenely massive diff. People would've yelled at me. You can imagine how the government can be.

Comment: Sure. I guess the govt would prefer smaller diffs to having its code meet trailing whitespace standards. And I guess it does not matter for them that any diffing tool can be told to ignore whitespace changes. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: @torazaburo Well I tried changing the options to the difftool, but they got a little upset there as well :) I've long since left that job (this question is from 2013), but thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but https://github.com/lewang/ws-butler might help in such cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Sean's snippet, adjusted for Magit v2:

```
(defun my-magit-delete-trailing-whitespace-from-file ()
  "Remove whitespace from the current file."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (magit-diff-visit-file-worktree (magit-file-at-point))
    (delete-trailing-whitespace)
    (save-buffer)
    (kill-buffer))
  (magit-refresh))
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is there any way to limit this to the hunk? Does the overlay in magit-status have any information about where the hunk comes from? If so, you could use that information to narrow before deleting the whitespace.

Comment: For a hunk section `(magit-section-value (magit-current-section))` would return something like `("(defun module-rebuild ()" "-73,6" "+73,8")`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @tarsius's for your great trick! I managed to tweak it to remove just trailing whitespaces for the line at point. This requires the 'ws-trim' package installed.

```
(defun my-magit-delete-trailing-whitespace ()
  "Remove whitespace from the current file."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (magit-diff-visit-file-worktree (magit-file-at-point))
    (ws-trim-line nil)
    (save-buffer)
    (kill-buffer))
  (magit-refresh))

(add-hook 'magit-status-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (local-set-key [deletechar] 'my-magit-delete-trailing-whitespace)))
```

I'm binding the delete key since that isn't used for anything useful in `magit-status-mode`.